# Capitalization in angular's dynamic attribute directive

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using Angular 2 and Ionic 2 to build an app. Currently, I'm building a dynamic side menu. Ionic provides a directive called `menuClose` to signify that clicking a button will close a side menu.

I need to add that directive to some but not all buttons in my side menu conditionally, so I decided to use the `[attr.menuClose]="..."` construct.

This works fine but in my app, instead of getting the directive `menuClose`, I instead get `menuclose` (note capitalization).

Can I somehow get Angular 2 to respect my chosen capitalization?

**My Template**

```
<button [attr.menuClose]="''" ion-item *ngFor="let item of this.root" (click)="openItem(item)">
  {{item.text}}
</button>
```

**The result I get:**

```
<button class="item-block item item-ios" ion-item="" tappable="" menuclose="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[attr.some-attribute]` is used for conditionally setting an actual html element like `src` or `href` or `name` or `id`, but not for binding a attribute directive.

Instead you will need to do something like:

You can do something like this:

```
<button *ngIf="someCondition" menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let item of this.root" (click)="openItem(item)">
  {{item.text}}
</button>
<button *ngIf="!someCondition" ion-item *ngFor="let item of this.root" (click)="openItem(item)">
  {{item.text}}
</button>
```

This is not ideal as you have code duplication.

A better option would be to see how menuClose works, and extend it to except a condition.

**UPDATE**

The source for menuClose is here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/dbfc183cac036099603f9e51611bfccbc900a08b/src/components/menu/menu-close.ts

You can create a simple directive that does this, and takes a boolean predicate to enable or disable the behaviour.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myMenuClose]'
})
export class MyMenuClose {

  @Input() myMenuClose: boolean;

  constructor(private _menu: MenuController) {}

  @HostListener('click')
  close() {
    if (this.myMenuClose) {
      const menu = this._menu.get();
      menu && menu.close();
    }
  }
}
```

This directive has slightly different behavior than `menuClose`. You pass a boolean condition to it to enable or disable it.

```
<button [myMenuClose]="someCondition" ion-item *ngFor="let item of this.root" (click)="openItem(item)">
  {{item.text}}
</button>
```

Comment: Luckily this is quite a small bit of code, so the duplication is fine for now and I'll accept this answer... But Angular needs to have a feature that allows this. (Ideally, this one!)